# Blackberry Messanger desktop client

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I would like to develop a Blackberry Messanger desktop client, something similar to [Fixmo Web Messenger](http://fixmo.com/fwm) but open source. The idea is to connect the smartphone via USB or Wi-Fi and use BBM from the computer.
Does anybody know any library or documentation to connect to BBM?

EDITED:
I found this, https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/appworld/bbm. I'll see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this currently using the present BBM APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That means Fixmo Web Messenger used to work but not any more?